# Android Studio display SQL data in TextView boxes (Java)

Tags: java, android, sql-server, xml, database-connection

I'm trying to create an android app to print off labels, I am currently just getting started and new to android development. The app "should" display 7 textbox's on the screen each being a new column from SQL. The app runs but doesn't display any of the data, I haven't been able to find anything online to help me but I imagine that's something small is missing in the code. I have added my 3 files that are being used and my AndroidManifest.xml all below. Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zebraprint_v2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Connection connect;
    String connectionresult = "";
    SimpleAdapter ad;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void GetTextFromSQL(View v)
    {
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tx4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView tx5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView tx6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        TextView tx7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);


        try
        {
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.initConnection("ServerName", "DatabaseName");
            if(connect != null)
            {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM SQLTableName";
                Statement st = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    tx1.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    tx2.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    tx3.setText(rs.getString(3));
                    tx4.setText(rs.getString(4));
                    tx5.setText(rs.getString(5));
                    tx6.setText(rs.getString(6));
                    tx7.setText(rs.getString(7));

                }
            }
            else
            {
                connectionresult = "Check Connection";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error Connection Unsuccessful", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

ConnectionHelper.java

```
package com.example.zebraprint_v2;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionHelper {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    public static Connection initConnection(String server, String database) {

        String ip, port, un, pass, db = null;
        // Log in
        switch(server){
            case "ServerName":
                ip = "00.0.000.00";
                port = "0000";
                un = "UserName";
                pass = "PassWord";
                db = database; //"DatabaseName";
                break;
                /*
            case "ServerName":
                ip = "00.0.000.00";
                port = "000";
                un = "Username";
                pass = "Password";
                db = database; //"DatabaseName";
                break;
                 */
            // reached if inputted an invalid server
            default:
                ip = null;
                port = null;
                db = null;
                un = null;
                pass = null;
        }

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((policy));
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + pass + ";";
            // this statement breaks out if timeout, change integer for larger wait time if necessary
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectURL);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // cant connext to network, try again later
            Log.e("Error ", ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LoadKANBAN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.046" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.133" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.306" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.392" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.479" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.173"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LoadData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="GetTextFromSQL"
        android:text="Load KANBAN Card PrintOut"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.926" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.zebraprint_v2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ZebraPrintV2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here are the error that are in my Logcat

```
28823-28823/com.example.zebraprint_v2 E/e.zebraprint_v: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

28823-29002/com.example.zebraprint_v2 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.zebraprint_v2

28823-29002/com.example.zebraprint_v2 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

28823-29002/com.example.zebraprint_v2 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.zebraprint_v2

28823-29002/com.example.zebraprint_v2 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in your log? Is the query actually running? I think the first step is figuring what is running and what isn't.

Comment: The errors that I am receiving have been added to the bottom of the post, thanks